User's session gets assigned to another user
I have 1 spring mvc web application where some users are randomly getting assigned another user's session & are able to view profile and make orders on that account. Upon not receiving the confirmation email they realise that it's some random account.
Has anyone came across this issue using spring 4.x.x and tomcat 8.x.x?
PS: this is only happening for web users, apps working fine.

No, nobody has ever encountered something like that as long as one has configured the application properly. Sorry, that's not a Spring issue, that's on you.

Probably thread bounded beans leaking data :)

Let me guess, you are using a controller and decided to "cache" things at the class level, don't do things like that. However as you haven't posted any code / configuration on pages/controllers that show this symptom this will be impossible to answer with certainty.

no cache anywhere at web application, this is only happening at web app only

@being_ethereal So you let us know that you don't use any cache, but you refuse to provide related code which Deinum requested to being able to help? I only can speech for myself, at least I'm not a magician and without code I can't imaginate what problem you have. Or have you already solved the problem? Then you should post your current solution as an answer so that others may profit from it.

@Slevin no need to get offended, I would hv shared the configuration if anything was of importance. I, myself hv not encountered this issue in my career. It's just a simple xml based spring4 project & everything was good until it got deployed on Kubernetes pod and app resources got cached via cloudfront
